# Why does this site (non-meta part) use light blue link text on a white background?

Tags: discussion, bug, design

Isn't the light blue text on white background of this site (non-meta part) difficult to read? Not enough light/dark contrast, IMO.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/why-do-links-use-very-similar-colours-for-visited-hover-and-regular-links?rq=1